# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY error thrown in random places

Tags: security, sharing, einstein, dmlexception

Recently I've started getting error message:

> System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, Access to entity 'AIInsightValue' denied: []

What's interesting it happens randomly while performing operations like closing Opportunities, updating Work Order statuses and closing Orders.
Moreover on second ORG I've spotted similar error, but it throws different message

> System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, Access to entity 'CollabDocumentMetricRecord' denied: []

I've double checked permissions, user privileges and Sharing and Security settings. What's more intereting it occurs inconsistently. There are "windows" when placing orders and processing works as it should work, but after 30-40 mins ORG is unusable because of this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the record access of the following record by querying on `UserRecordAccess`

```
SELECT RecordId,MaxAccessLevel,HasAllAccess,
    HasDeleteAccess,
    HasEditAccess,
    HasReadAccess,
    HasTransferAccess
FROM UserRecordAccess
WHERE UserId = 'The UserId of the user with whom you are getting error'
AND RecordId = 'Pass the record id for which you are getting this error'
```

This will given you clear picture of what kind of access is there for the user.
If there is no access, then you might have to check if the access to this records gets assigned by some related record.

The root cause should be in sharing the record access. You might have access from Permissionset or Profile, but you may have defined related or object access as `Private` or `Controlled By Parent` etc... And might not have any read or readwrite permissions from Sharing rules.

Comment: This is not a solution. As I mentioned before. Sharing rules and permissions are correct. All operations are performed as System Admin. Main point is that sometimes ORG throws this error but sometimes it works properlly while performing same actions like placing an order, or updating order status.

Comment: Can you run the query shown above and check the access?

Comment: I've queried access levels as you suggessted.
MaxAccessLevel - All,
HasAllAccess - true,
HasDeleteAccess - true,
HasEditAccess - true,
HasReadAccess - true,
HasTransferAccess - true

Comment: Which Record ID did you pass?

Comment: Record ID which update casued this error. I can give you Id, but without access to my ORG it won't tell you anything.